# Using computeIfAbsent method in java?

Tags: java

I get the general idea behind it e.g puts new set in map if not there but actually getting it to work has been difficult! so i currently have something like this. the example in javadocs isnt quite sinking

```
if (!result.containsKey(someID)) {
    hashy = new HashSet<>();
    result.put(someID, hashy);
} else {
    hashy = result.get(someID);
}
```

as you can see from the above if the result (which is a map of <String, Set>) dosnt contain someID then we are putting someID and the new hashset in it.

How would i use the computeIfAbsent function here instead ?

```
hashy = new HashSet<>();

result.computeIfAbsent(someID, k-> result.put(someID, hashy ));
```

ive tried this but it dosnt seem to be working

any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) is that you don't construct the new object *unless* you actually need it, and you also don't explicitly call `put`. `computeIfAbsent` does all of that for you.

So the equivalent to your original `hashy` code

```
if (!result.containsKey(someID)) {
    hashy = new HashSet<>();
    result.put(someID, hashy);
} else {
    hashy = result.get(someID);
}
```

is merely

```
hashy = result.computeIfAbsent(someID, _ -> new HashSet<...>());
```

Note that, depending on your use case, Java may or may not be able to infer the generic type of the `HashSet`, so you may have to specify the type in the angled brackets explicitly.